# Hide navigation bar with angularjs using ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**SOLVED**

Good Evening,

I'm having trouble with hiding navigation sidebar using ng-if from angular. I declare the activetab on $route but it still didn't work. Here's the code.

Html:

```
<header ng-if="$route.current.activetab !== 'login'">
<div class="col s3">
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav fixed">
        <li class="logo">
            <a href="#" id="logo-container" class="brand-logo">BRAND LOGO</a>
        </li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

$route config on app.js:

```
experimentApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    var baseTitle = 'Experiment';

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        title: baseTitle + ' - Home',
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.php',
        activetab: 'home'
    }).when('/login', {
        title: baseTitle + ' - Login',
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.php',
        activetab: 'login',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });

}]);
```

**Answer**:

i created new controller named navigation, partitioning the html and put some code on root controller.

Navigation Controller:

```
experimentApp.controller('navigation',
['$scope', '$location', '$route', function($scope, $location, $route) {
    $scope.navigation = function() {
        if (!$scope.active('/login')) {
            return 'partials/navigation.php';
        }
    }
}]);
```

$scope.active on root controller:

```
$scope.active = function(path) {
        return $location.path().match(new RegExp(path + '.*', 'i')) != null;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<header ng-controller="navigation" ng-include="navigation()"></header>
```

Thanks to anyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the routes change in your app, you should try using the events of the router. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

You can create a `$scope` variable, then change it when `$routeChangeSuccess` event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the scope from a `$route`by using the route's `resolve` attribute :

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    title: baseTitle + ' - Home',
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.php',
    resolve: { activetab: "home" }
}).when('/login', {
    title: baseTitle + ' - Login',
    templateUrl: 'partials/login.php',
    controller: 'LoginController',
    resolve: { activetab: "login" }
});
```

To use with the following ng-if: `ng-if="activetab !== 'login'"`.

There are multiple other solutions, such as using `$location` to monitor your page url, enriching the scope from a controller, listening to $route change events, etc.

Comment: i got an injector module error when i tried this one, i'm sorry i'm really new to this